# How I can compare two values of same generic type?

Tags: c#

Following code won't compile:

```cs
class Test<T> where T : class, IComparable
{
    public bool IsGreater(T t1, T t2)
    {
        return t1 > t2; // Cannot apply operator '>' to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
    }
}
```

How I can make it work? I want it to work for T = `int`, `double`, `DateTime`, etc.

Comment: [`IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable.compareto?view=net-5.0) gives you a `CompareTo` method. So `t1.CompareTo(t2) > 0`

Comment: ... and int, double and DateTime are not a class. Remove the class constraint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=net-5.0) interface that you have used here as the type constraint gives you a [`CompareTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable.compareto?view=net-5.0) method. So you can do something like this:

```
public bool IsGreater(T t1, T t2)
{
    return t1.CompareTo(t2) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

While currently you can't do exactly that (and you need to use solution by [@DavidG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69899585/2501279)) there is a preview feature you [can enable](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/#trying-out-the-features) called [generic math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/) which is based on [static abstract interface members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/static-abstract-interface-methods) and ships with interface specially for that purpose:

```
[RequiresPreviewFeatures]
public interface IComparisonOperators<TSelf, TOther> : IComparable, IComparable<TOther>, IEqualityOperators<TSelf, TOther>, IEquatable<TOther> where TSelf : IComparisonOperators<TSelf, TOther>
{
    static bool operator <(TSelf left, TOther right);

    static bool operator <=(TSelf left, TOther right);

    static bool operator >(TSelf left, TOther right);

    static bool operator >=(TSelf left, TOther right);
}
```

So in future (or right now if you want to be an early adopter) you will be able to do (if no major overhaul comes for this preview):

```
class Test<T> where T : IComparisonOperators<T, T>
{
    public bool IsGreater(T t1, T t2)
    {
        return t1 > t2; 
    }
}
```

Note that for `Test` to support `int`, `double`, `DateTime`, etc. you need to remove `class` constraint (with or without this preview feature).

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to compare two values of same generic type.

```
public bool IsGreater(T t1, T t2)
{
    return t1.CompareTo(t2) > 0;
}
```