# Generic class where type must implement IEquatable

Tags: c#, generics, equality

I'm trying to create a generic "property" class that maintains both it's current value and the last value.

```
public class GenericTrackingProperty<T> where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    private T _oldValue;
    private T _currentValue;

    public T Value
    {
        get { return _currentValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _currentValue)
            {
                _oldValue = _currentValue;
                _currentValue = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Despite the use of the ***where*** in the class definition to ensure the generic type is equatable the compiler complains about the comparison "if (value != _currentValue" giving an error "Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if (!value.Equals(_currentValue))`

Comment: You can use a stack to pop and push the values if you want to maintain a history.

Comment: The same issue like with `IComparable` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69899514)

Comment: Pro tip: The docs are quite good for .NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1.  If you look, the only member that interface has is the `Equals` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1.equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`IEquatable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1) doesn't contain operators, but it contains the [`Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1.equals) method.
Use it instead of the equality operator:

```
if (!value.Equals(_currentValue))
```

Or, null-aware:

```
if (value == null ? _currentValue == null : !value.Equals(_currentValue))
```

Comment: Or `value?.Equals(_currentValue) is false`.

Answer (score 1):

Let .NET [compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1?view=net-6.0) both values for you (while checking for `null` etc):

```
if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, _currentValue)) {
  ... 
}
```

You can use `value.Equals` but in this case you have to check for `null`:

```
if (value == null && _currentValue != null || !value.Equals(_currentValue)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: You don't even need the `IEquatable` constraint with this method.

Comment: @DStanley I would say that it is up for debate, this constraint allows to prevent passing types which don't have custom equality defined, which can be a valid use case (for example prevent _default_ by reference equality).

Comment: should not it be `!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals`?

Comment: @Guru Stron: thank you! You are quite right, it must have been `Default`